# Check if all interfaces contained in an array have all fields - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I've just created an array of typed interfaces.
Given that some interface fields are optional, I'm curious if there is a *smart* way to check if **all** interfaces contained in the array have filled fields.
This is my interface:

```
export interface BibliographicCitation {
  authors?: HTMLCollectionOf<Element>;
  title: string;
  date?: Element;
}
```

And this is the way how I fill the array:

**EDIT**

```
citations.forEach(citation => {
    if (citation.getElementsByTagName('author').length === 0 &&
        citation.getElementsByTagName('title').length === 0 &&
        citation.getElementsByTagName('date').length === 0) {

        const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
           title: citation.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        };

        if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
            bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
        }
    } 
    else {
        const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
           authors: citation.getElementsByTagName('author'),
           title: String(citation.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]).replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
           date: citation.getElementsByTagName('date')[0],
        };

        if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
           bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
        }
    }
});
```

In the end, how do I check that all interfaces entered have filled fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use variable `isAllProperties` and check:

```
let isAllProperties = false;
if (citation.getElementsByTagName('author').length === 0 &&
    citation.getElementsByTagName('title').length === 0 &&
    citation.getElementsByTagName('date').length === 0) {
    // ...
    isAllProperties = true;
} else {

}

if (isAllProperties ) {
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
let isAllProperties = [];
citations.forEach(citation => {
if (citation.getElementsByTagName('author').length === 0 &&
    citation.getElementsByTagName('title').length === 0 &&
    citation.getElementsByTagName('date').length === 0) {

    const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
       title: citation.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
    };

    if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
        bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
    }
    isAllProperties.push({isAll: true, interfacedCitation});
} 
else {
    const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
       authors: citation.getElementsByTagName('author'),
       title: String(citation.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]).replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
       date: citation.getElementsByTagName('date')[0],
    };

    if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
       bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
    }

    isAllProperties.push({isAll: false, interfacedCitation});
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this one help you

```js
let getAuthor = citation.getElementsByTagName('author');
let getTitle = citation.getElementsByTagName('author');
let getDate = citation.getElementsByTagName('author');
let conditionTitle:any;
const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
 authors: this.getAuthor ,
 title: this.conditionTitle ,
 date: this.getDate[0]
};
if (this.getAuthor && this.getTitle && this.getDate) {
this.conditionTitle = citation.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
     bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
    }
} else {
    this.conditionTitle = this.getTitle;
    if (!bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { 
     bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); 
    }
}
```